# Different output from encodeURIComponent vs URLSearchParams

Tags: url, oauth-2.0, query-string

I built an oauth2 url with query params using `URLSearchParams` API. However, the output URL didn't return an expected url. Can anyone help me understand the difference between those two APIs and how can I get the same result as the output of `encodeURIComponent`, using `URLSearchParams`?

```js
const expected = encodeURIComponent('code id_token'); // code%20id_token

const search = new URLSearchParams();
search.set('response_type', 'code id_token');
search.toString(); // code+id_token
```

Comment: It's not just spaces.  Try `encodeURIComponent("(bar)")` vs. `new URLSearchParams({ foo: "(bar)" }) + ""`.

Comment: The arguments for both functions are different. Did you mean it? I dont get what you really intent to explain. L

Comment: I'm just underlining your point. `encodeURIComponent()` leaves `"(bar)"` as is, while `URLSearchParams()` turns it into `"%28bar%29"`. I don't know why `URLSearchParams()` is different.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [WHATWG](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams), `URLSearchParams` uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. While it's suitable for decoding URL queries, for encoding it can lead to unexpected results such as spaces being encoded as `+` and extra characters such as `~` being percent-encoded. It's better to use `encodeURIComponent` instead:

Having an object:

```js
const params = {
  text1: 'aaa bbb',
  text2: '-._*~()'
}
```

Instead of:

```js
url.search = (new URLSearchParams(params)).toString()
```

Use:

```js
url.search = Object.entries(params)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
  .join('&')
```

Also, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) even `encodeURIComponent` doesn't conform to newer [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which defines more characters to escape, for example `*`. While it's probably safe not to escape these additional characters if you aren't using them as field separators, if you want to be strictly conformant to latest RFC, use this updated implementation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```js
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

A playground for experimenting:

```js
const params = {
  text1: 'aaa bbb',
  text2: '-._*~()'
}

const url1 = new URL('http://example.com')
const search1 = new URLSearchParams(params)
url1.search = search1 // Incorrect
console.log('URLSearchParams', url1.toString())

function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()
    })
}
const url2 = new URL('http://example.com')
const search2 = Object
  .entries(params)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${fixedEncodeURIComponent(key)}=${fixedEncodeURIComponent(value)}`)
  .join('&')
url2.search = search2 // Correct
console.log('fixedEncodeURIComponent', url2.toString())
```

Comment: Note, that the `toString(16)` produces hex-strings with lowercase chars (for example with `*` char), while `encodeURIComponent` produces uppercase chars. Allthough it didn't caused any errors, it got me very confused during tests-writing due to the mixed cases. Maybe you add `.toUpperCase()` to have them return consistent cases. Otherwise thank you for the great solution!